# Custom procedure for Text File checking, assigning and reading? DELPHI

Tags: delphi

Ive tried making a procedure to do exactly what the title says, although I'm not having any luck with it so far.

Here it is:

```
procedure TForm1.ReadFile(a: File; b : string); // File type not allowed here.
begin
  if FileExists(a) = False
    then
      begin
        ShowMessage ('File not found, program shutting down');
        Application.Terminate;
      end;
  AssignFile (b, a); // Incompatible types
  Reset(b); //Incompatible types
end;
```

Firstly, is this even possible? If so, please show me how!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :-

```
procedure TForm1.ReadFile(Const pFileName : string);
Var
  lFile : File;
begin
  if FileExists(pFileName) Then
  Begin
    AssignFile(lFile, pFileName);
    Reset(lFile);
    // Do whatever processing is required.
    CloseFile(lFile);
  End
  Else
  begin
    ShowMessage ('File not found, program shutting down');
    Application.Terminate;
  end;
end;
```

For what it's worth, you shouldn't really be using the old Pascal intrinsics for file handling any more. You would be better served looking at the documentation for `TFileStream` and its descendant classes.

Comment: Would you call it like : `ReadFile(Items.txt)` or `ReadFile('Items.txt')`?

Comment: @Link The parameter is a string therefore the second one is correct. i.e. `ReadFile('Items.txt');`